# Replacing the last three characters in a string if they match a condition

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I am trying to take a user inputed string and, if it ends with `'ion'`, replace the last three characters of the string and add an `'e'`.

```
def ion2e(s):
    if s[-3:]=='ion':
        print (s[-3:]+'e')
    else:
        print (s)
```

Comment: Can you describe the debugging efforts you undertook when you saw the incorrect result?

Comment: You are using `s[-3:]` for both the suffix (in the condition) and everything *prior* to the suffix (in the body of the `if` statement). One of those--and which should be obvious--is wrong.

Comment: Remember to "accept" your favourite answer and up-vote the worthiest (I was doing this until I ran out of votes for today).  *Accept* lets SO retire the question properly.

Answer (score 6):

Use `str.endswith`:

```
>>> def ion2e(s):
...     return s[:-3] + 'e' if s.endswith('ion') else s
... 
>>> ion2e('xxxion')
'xxxe'
>>> ion2e('xx')
'xx'
```

Answer (score 4):

`s[-3:]` says

> give me s starting 3 digits backwards from the end, and going to the end

But what you want is `s` *up to* 3 digits backwards from the end. Which would be:

```
s[:-3]
```

So your whole code should be:

```
def ion2e(s):
    if s[-3:]=='ion':
        print (s[:-3]+'e')
    else:
        print (s)
```

Comment: Thank you! I realize this mistake now.

Answer (score 2):

Move the colon in your print.  You need the string *up to* the -3rd element, not the end of the string.

```
def ion2e(s):
    if s[-3:]=='ion':
        print (s[:-3]+'e')
    else:
        print (s)

t = "constitution"
ion2e(t)
```

Also, are you familiar with single-statement **if** expressions?  Your function might be reduced to this, if you want to return the value instead of printing it.

```
def ion2e(s):
    return s[:-3]+'e' if s[-3:]=='ion' else s
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm new to all this and genuinely am trying to figure out. I think moving the colon fixed my issue!

Comment: Im a beginner, so I know my instructor is looking for something more along the lines of what i put up. I just goofed on the colon. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

You may also want to use *re*

```
import re
print (re.sub("ion$", "e", 'station'))
```

Comment: >Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.< - Jamie Zawinski

Comment: @Matthias that's true. but there is something very readable about using a one liner regexp